# Android market not showing my app in search results

Tags: android, search, google-play

I have uploaded my app 5 days ago. But till now it was not listed in search results. I have searched almost 1000 results but it was not there in those results.

I have asked the same question to support team they replied a vague answer, they said that search is based on manifest and publisher, app title, description etc. But nothing had helped me. My app doesn't require any special permissions. Here is the code from manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mathsforkidslite"
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="1.0.4" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="true"/>
<application>.........</application>
<manifest>
```

Every activity's screen orientation is Landscape

When I used the direct URL it is showing my app, but it is not showing in search and also the following scenarios worked

1) Using double quotes it worked (like **"maths for kids"**)

2) Using publisher id it worked (i.e **Yogasaikrishna**)

3) Using package name it worked (i.e **com.mathsforkidslite**)

But it is not at all showing in the search results when I search with application name or any other keywords, the description is also nice for the app, so at least it should be displayed withing 500 results.

Can anyone please let me know if there is anything wrong from my side?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is a marketing question.

Comment: As stated, this is not a programming question. However, it's not so odd that you can't find your app easily. There are a ton of other "math for kids" apps out there, so it will be harder to get to the top of the list. Your ranking is based on a lot of factors, including amount of downloads and ratings. As long as there are other apps with more downloads and higher ratings, your app is likely to end up below them.

Answer (score 2):

This is ur app link

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=com.mathsforkidslite

if it is?then i think ur apps have very less comments so it not displayed in search result.
so increase feedback and comments to promote it.

Comment: As it was uploaded just 5 days back, and without getting in search results how can i expect to get feedback and comments :(

Comment: You've just released your application, unless you publicize it NO ONE is going to search for it.

I suggest you get a few friends to rate for you and publicize the application on forums like `xda-developers`. If you respond to people immediately when they have a problem, they will give you a good review. It's all about marketing.